# What are the differences between weapons upgrades?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one

I want to know what it means different weapon upgrades. I understand that ammunition offers more ammunition in total.

What is energy and elite (with the translation of French into English, the names may differ)? I guess possibly energy increases the damage, but I have no certainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*power* simply provides more damage

elite gives a modification to how the weapon functions (like the final upgrade in previous games)

and you need to have ammo and power upgrades before you can buy the elite upgrade

Comment: I did not play the previous Ratchet yet. You can tell me more about improving elite? This may be an example, just so I understand. I do not have enough bolts in the game to see it by myself.

Comment: the combuster for example when upgraded to elite will shoot 3 bullets in a horizontal spread instead of 1 (still only using 1 ammo)